# Nothing coming in Output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

I was making this website with React. First, I got an error saying `useState is defined but never used` for navbar component.
So, I added this to my ESLint config field in package.json:

```
"rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
```

Still, no change.
I tried adding `"extends": "react/recommended"` and still there was no change.

What do I do?

This is my ESLint config field in package.json:

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react",
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import navbar from './components/navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact />
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`import navbar from './components/navbar';` looks disabled and shows `navbar is declared but its value is never used` when I hover over that line.

This is my navbar.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


function navbar() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-container">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
                        CRUXx
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default navbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Companante's name should start with a capital letter.

And the useState just needs to be deleted from the import line, Because it is not needed.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't know about that. First time trying out React. It worked.

Comment: I'm happy :-)  .